# How to determine if a cp process in terminal (command line) is stuck?

Tags: macos, command-line

I've forced myself into the habit of utilizing the command line "cp" command on my OS X machines to copy over large directories rather than the usual "click and drag" method. However, for the first time it seems like the process might be stuck.

I've used the Ctrl + t command during the process to determine if something is still active. It's output is as shown below:

```
load: 1.79  cmd: cp 657 running 23.54u 422.25s
load: 1.73  cmd: cp 657 running 23.54u 422.25s
load: 1.91  cmd: cp 657 running 23.54u 422.25s
load: 1.97  cmd: cp 657 running 23.54u 422.25s
load: 1.34  cmd: cp 657 running 23.54u 422.25s
load: 1.33  cmd: cp 657 running 23.54u 422.25s
```

Please note that the output above was generated by the ctrl + t command at intervals with a few minutes in between. I'm starting to lean towards it being stuck given the "running ..." being the same in each line.

Should I just cancel the process via ctrl + c and start over with a merge cp command?

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referencing "man cp" on terminal—

> "-v    Cause cp to be verbose, showing files as they are copied."

By using the -v flag, it prints out a log of files being copied over in real time. It acts as a kind of activity log or monitor, if you will. Although @john elemans provided a great tip with appending "&" and going to the directory where files are being copied to, it wasn't exactly what I was looking for, especially when comparing the option to use the -v flag.

**Follow up edit:**
I should also point out that by the process stated above, unless you're copying/moving over very large files, the "activity" log will be rapidly printing out the paths of the files being copied. So, if it's "stuck" for too long on any given file, investigate that particular file and determine if its size warrants the length of time the log has been "stuck" on this file. From there, you can make a reasonable assessment as to weather or not it is and proceed to cancel or hold out.

P.S. - I forgot that I had posted this question so long ago.

Answer (score 1):

I generally put the cp command into the background (put an & at the end of the line). Then you can just go to the designation folder and look to see if the files are being added.

fwiw; I regularly had to move folders with hundreds of thousands of files a few years ago and cp did indeed hang up occasionally. I haven't had to do this recently so i don't know if it has improved or not.